# List of O(n^2) and O(n^3) algorithms that aren't linear algebra?

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, blas

I've been reading a lot of [papers](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/indices/a-tree/d/Demmel%3aJames.html) on performance optimizations for matrix-vector multiplication (BLAS2) and matrix-matrix multiplication (BLAS3). I'd like to think about if/how these optimizations would apply to O(n^2) and O(n^3) algorithms that don't cleanly reduce to dense or sparse linear algebra.

It's easy to find lists of NP-complete or NP-hard algorithms, but I haven't found a good breakdown of common (and not-so-common) polynomial time algorithms. Can anyone suggest a list of polynomial-time problems for which the best known algorithm is O(n^2) or O(n^3)?

Edit: To make this more concrete, I'm looking for something like [this list of *NP-complete* problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems), but for *polynomial* problems with n^2 or n^3 algorithms instead.

Comment: Note: it's up for debate whether this question belongs on StackOverflow, MathOverflow, math.stackexchange, or cstheory.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: It's worth noting that the complexity of level-two and level-three BLAS operations are actually formally O(n) and O(n^3/2); the input matrices are themselves quadratic in what people usually think of as "n".

The techniques commonly used for dense linear algebra do not really apply directly to other problem domains, because they tend to make heavy use of linearity of the problem.

Next: some of the most common examples of O(n^2) algorithms are the naive algorithms for sorting, integer multiplication, and computing discrete Fourier transforms.  In all of these cases, better algorithms with lower complexity exist.  Similarly, there is a large number of naive O(n^3) algorithms.

One can apply dense linear algebra techniques to computing the DFT (since it is also linear), but you can do much better still by using one of the FFT algorithms, so in practice no one does this.

As far as non-naive algorithms go, it's been far too long since I had to teach a complexity course; IIRC, the best known algorithm for deciding if a string is in a context-free language is O(n^3).